# How to solve $\frac{\sqrt{27}+\sqrt{75}}{\sqrt{48}}$

Tags: solution-verification, radicals

So I was looking through the homepage of Youtube to see if there were any math equations that I thought that I might be able to solve, when I happened to come across [this](https://youtu.be/-CHDVhuslQQ) math equation by Learncommunolizer. The equation in question was$$\text{Solve }\text{ }\frac{\sqrt{27}+\sqrt{75}}{\sqrt{48}}$$which I thought that I might be able to solve. Here is my attempt at solving the equation:$\color{white}{\require{cancel}{.}}$
$$\frac{\sqrt{27}+\sqrt{75}}{\sqrt{48}}$$$$=\frac{\sqrt{3\cdot3\cdot3}+\sqrt{5\cdot5\cdot3}}{\sqrt{2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3}}$$$$=\frac{3\sqrt3+5\sqrt3}{4\sqrt{3}}$$$$=\frac{3\sqrt3}{4\sqrt3}+\frac{5\sqrt3}{4\sqrt3}$$$$=\frac{3\cancel{\sqrt3}}{4\cancel{\sqrt3}}+\frac{5\cancel{\sqrt3}}{4\cancel{\sqrt3}}$$$$=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{5}{4}$$$$=\text{ }\frac{8}{4}$$$$=2$$**My question**

---

Is my solution correct, or what could I do to attain the correct solution, or attain it more easily?

Comment: I am so sorry about all of the edits right away, I should have caught the "Mathjax not being able to format the question content due to me hitting the enter key" during the writing phase, that is 100% my fault and I am so sorry.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, and you can make it more easily by using $3\sqrt3+5\sqrt3=8\sqrt3$

Comment: Your arrows and iff should be $=$ signs.

Comment: @MathFail Ah okay that makes sense

Comment: @A.Goodier I'll fix that :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also proceed as follows :

$\dfrac{\sqrt{27}\!+\!\sqrt{75}}{\sqrt{48}}= \dfrac{\sqrt3\!\left(\sqrt{27}\!+\!\sqrt{75}\right)}{\sqrt3\!\cdot\!\sqrt{48}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{81}\!+\!\sqrt{225}}{\sqrt{144}}=\\[12pt]=\dfrac{9\!+\!15}{12}=\dfrac{24}{12}=2\;.$